На смартфоне ширину сайта 768px уменьшать в масштабе по ширине браузера смартфона
Версталось приложение для телеграма. Вот ссылка на приложение. Верстка не влазит. Вот моя шапка
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16"> 
    <title></title>
</head>

Верстку шириной 768px нужно уменьшать по масштабу по ширине окна браузера. Как это сделать?

Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Вы имеете ввиду что-то вот такое ? 
